# Very large and same predicitons by Linear Regression in Scikit pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, scikit-learn-pipeline

I have a LR pipeline that I train over a dataset and save it. DUring the training, I also test it on X_test and the predicitons look okay. SO I save the model as joblib and load again to do prediction on a data.

The predicitons on new data gives very large prediction and mostly the same for all rows.

Here is the pipeline:

```
feature_cleaner =  Pipeline(steps=[
        ("id_col_remover", columnDropperTransformer(id_cols)),
        ("missing_remover", columnDropperTransformer(miss_cols)),
        ("nearZero_remover", columnDropperTransformer(nearZero_cols))
    ])

zero_Setter = Pipeline(steps=[
    ("zero_imp", ZeroImputer(fill_zero_cols)),
    ('case_age_month', positiveTransformer(['CASE_AGE_MONTHS']))
])

numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = "constant", fill_value=-1, add_indicator=True)),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])
categotical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = "constant", fill_value='Unknown')),
    ('scaler', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))
])
preprocess_ppl = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('numeric', numeric_transformer, make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
        ('categorical', categotical_transformer, make_column_selector(dtype_include='category'))
    ], remainder='drop'
)
steps=[
        ('zero_imputer', zero_Setter),
        ('cleaner', feature_cleaner),
        ("preprocessor", preprocess_ppl),
        ("estimator", LinearRegression(n_jobs=-1))
    ]

pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=steps
)
```

`feature_remover` just deletes some features, zero_setter replaces NA with zero for some cols, categorical transformer oneHotEncodes the categorical variables in the data and a numeric transformer for numeric handling.

The predictions I make within the same script look okay:
[image]

but when I download the joblib (as the training job is on cloud) and run prediction for a subset of data I get predictions that look like this:
[image]

I am not sure why is this happening since the data goes throught the same pipeline duriong training and scoring.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, during training I was converting some features to categorical but during prediciton I forgot to do so, therefore there were no encoded features during prediction.

After fixing this during prediction, the error got fixed.

```
for each in cat_features:
    print(each)
    data[each] = data[each].astype(str)
    data[each] = data[each].astype('category')
```